# Wrapping a collection view in a view controller nil delegate error

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, viewcontroller

I have a view controller wrapping a scrollview which then holds a collection view and a content view. When I run I get a null pointer exception assigning the collection view delegate in viewDidLoad:

```
collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

Not sure why, i have implemented protocols and made a connection to view controller as follows;

```
class LayoutController2 : UIViewController , UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate {

 @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
```

Any Input appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is the `collectionView` outlet connected in the storyboard? It's implicit unwrapped so if you access the delegate and the collectionView is not connected it will blow up

Comment: Thanks, re-did the outlet to the controller and also forgot to to connect the contents of cell to its custom class, but ok now